# How to debug and/or trace execution flow in WebMatrix?

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I am just getting into web development (from a Windows application development background), and WebMatrix seems like a good place to start, due to it's simplicity, and also because it looks like a useful stepping stone towards full ASP.NET MVC development.

However the lack of debugging tools hurts a bit, especially while trying to learn the fundamentals of development in the web environment.

Tracing the flow of execution, and displaying the trace data on the page, seems like a fairly basic capability for an absolute minimum debugging experience, but even that does not seem to be built into WebMatrix (or maybe I just haven't found it yet).

It is easy within a single page to set a trace variable, and then show that variable in the page layout.  But how does that help when I need to trace execution across other pages in the flow (e.g. Layout pages, _PageStart pages, etc), and even within my C# classes used during the page building process.

Is there a tracing capability within WebMatrix that I have not yet found?  Or alternatively, is there a way to implement a tracing facility that will work throughout the application, and not just in a single page? Even a third party product ($) would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of WebMatrix's simplicity (and for some, it's appeal) is the lack of bloat such as debuggers and tracing tools! Having said that, I wouldn't bet against a debugger appearing in a future release (along with Intellisense).

Within WebMatrix we have basic 'print variables to the page' cababilities with the `ServerInfo` and `ObjectInfo` objects which help with dumping raw info to the frontend. A quick tutorial for using these objects can be found on the asp.net site: [Introduction to Debugging.](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/17-introduction-to-debugging)

If you want to go deeper with actual IDE level debugging and tracing, then I suggest you use Visual Studio (any version will work fine, including the free Express edition).

Again there is an excellent introduction to doing this on the asp.net site: [Program ASP.NET Web Pages in Visual Studio.](http://www.asp.net/webmatrix/tutorials/program-asp-net-web-pages-in-visual-studio)

The key points are installing **Visual Web Developer 2010 Express** and **ASP.NET MVC3 RTM**. This will give you a handy 'Launch Visual Studio' button in WebMatrix too. Don't worry because you are still making Razor Web Pages sites, it just happens to be in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Razor Debugger](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/archive/2010/11/14/razor-debugger-for-asp-net-webpages.aspx)
 (currently at version 0.1) in the Packages (Nuget) area within WebMatrix.

Comment: Seems a bit better of an answer, considering the environment.

Answer (score 1):

WebMatrix harkens back to the classic days of debugging via alerts/print.  Not ideal, but there's a certain simplicity and art to it.  But, it's sometimes tough to get at your variables and whatnot when you have a problem in your code.  I've solved most of my debugging issues with a simple `Debug` class.

Make a file called Debug.cs in your App_Code directory with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;

public class TextWrittenEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public string Text { get; private set; }
    public TextWrittenEventArgs(string text) {
        this.Text = text;
    }
}

public class DebugMessages {
  StringBuilder _debugBuffer = new StringBuilder();

  public DebugMessages() {
    Debug.OnWrite += delegate(object sender, TextWrittenEventArgs e) { _debugBuffer.Append(e.Text); };
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return _debugBuffer.ToString();
  }
}

public static class Debug {
  public delegate void OnWriteEventHandler(object sender, TextWrittenEventArgs e);
  public static event OnWriteEventHandler OnWrite;

  public static void Write(string text) {
    TextWritten(text);
  }

  public static void WriteLine(string text) {
    TextWritten(text + System.Environment.NewLine);
  }

  public static void Write(string text, params object[] args) {
    text = (args != null ? String.Format(text, args) : text);
    TextWritten(text);
  }

  public static void WriteLine(string text, params object[] args) {
    text = (args != null ? String.Format(text, args) : text) + System.Environment.NewLine;
    TextWritten(text);
  }

  private static void TextWritten(string text) {
    if (OnWrite != null) OnWrite(null, new TextWrittenEventArgs(text));
  }
}
```

This will give you a static class called Debug, which has your typical WriteLine method.  Then, in your CSHTML pages, you can new-up the `DebugMessages` object.  You can `.ToString()` it to get debug messages out.

```
 var debugMsg = new DebugMessages();
 try {
    // code that's failing, but calls Debug.WriteLine() with key debug info
 }
 catch (Exception ex) {
   <p>@debugMsg.ToString()</p>
 }
```